# lmodern package with small caps in headlines

Tags: small-caps, lmodern

I need your help. I write my bachelor thesis and our prof wants us to use latex with lmodern characters. I have some fixed descriptions that need to be written in small caps in the headlines. The problem is that lmodern-package does not support small caps in bold face characters.

Does anybody know, how I can fix this problem or work around it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

Even if you are using latin modern generally, you can use cm-super (extended computer modern) for bold small caps, see 6 below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

1 Hello World

2 \textbf{Hello World}

3 \textsc{Hello World}

4 \textbf{\textsc{Hello World}}

5 \textsc{\textbf{Hello World}}

6 {\fontfamily{cmr}\textsc{\textbf{Hello World}}}





\end{document}
```