# How do you use Bold Small Caps with the moderncv package?

Tags: moderncv, bold, small-caps

[Overleaf Version](https://www.overleaf.com/read/nhvsvpwqrmpv)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % To switch to the T1 encoding

\firstname{John} % Your first name
\familyname{Doe} % Your last name

\begin{document}
\cvitem{Issue}{\textsc{Lorem, Ipsum, \textbf{Hello, Word}, Dolor, Sit, Amet}}

\end{document}
```

This will produce

[image: Hello and World are bold but not small caps]

How do I get the small caps to show up for the bold words, too?

I tried

```
\textsc{Lorem, Ipsum, \textbf{\textsc{Hello, World}}, Dolor, Sit, Amet}
```

but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Bold small cap fonts do not exist in the Latin Modern family. Maybe you can use Computer Modern Super as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367231/164314) or in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/334368/164314).

Comment: Please see my added answer! If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: Try some other standard font families `txfonts` `palatino`, etc. which have bold with small caps but the latin modern does not...

Answer (score 3):

Well, it depends on the used font, because not all fonts have glyphs for bold small caps. Please see that I added line `\moderncvstyle{classic}` to get a compilable code (please always test your given code before posting it).

For example you can use font `libertine`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % To switch to the T1 encoding

\moderncvstyle{classic}

\usepackage{libertine} % <==============================================

\firstname{John} % Your first name
\familyname{Doe} % Your last name


\begin{document}
\cvitem{Issue}{\textsc{Lorem, Ipsum, \textbf{Hello, Word}, Dolor, Sit, Amet}}
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: result with libertine]

Or you can use font `lmodern` (which does not have bold small caps) and use the bold small caps from font Computer Modern (`cmr`):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % To switch to the T1 encoding

\moderncvstyle{classic}

\usepackage{lmodern} 

\firstname{John} % Your first name
\familyname{Doe} % Your last name


\begin{document}
\cvitem{Issue}{\textsc{Lorem, Ipsum, \textbf{Hello, Word}, Dolor, Sit, Amet}}

\cvitem{Issue}{\textsc{Lorem, Ipsum, \textbf{Hello, Word}, Dolor, Sit, Amet} 
{\fontfamily{cmr}\textsc{\textbf{Hello World in cmr}}}} % <=============

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: result with cmr]